# Set questions relating to Integrals

Tags: integration

Say one is set a question like the following:

$${\int_0^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}} \cos\left({\frac{x}{2}}\right)dx$$

I know how to solve it to arrive at the numerical answer, but was wondering if the question states specifically "Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus" to solve the following, is this in anyway different than just solving a regular integral? Presumably all integrals are based on the fundamental theorem of calculus? I'm not really sure if this question makes any sense.

Comment: At first I was like the answer is "Yes, it's different, for insatnce think of integrals that you solve using the residue theorem." But then we also know that some of these integrals can be solved using the FTC. Or at least some of them after some manipulations you end up with an integral that has a known antiderivative. This question is deep. If you say integrals that you solve immediately by applying FTC, then there are some that don't work that way. For instance $$\int^\infty_0 e^{-x^2}dx$$ But even that can be solved with FTC after some manipulations.

Comment: @Shashi But $\exp(-x^2)$ has no "elementary" anti-derivative if I am not mistaken?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch after many steps you can reduce the calculations to the calculation of an integral which has an elementary antiderivative

Comment: @Shashi You mean for instance ith the polar coordinates trick? If that counts as "using FTC" then I agree the question is very deep . I assume they just meant "differentiate $2 \sin(x/2)$ and see what happens"